# Releasing memory of a bound Collection in a WPF MVVM application

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection, mvvm-light, observablecollection

First of all, by reading the different posts on the subject, I know that releasing memory in the .Net world is kind of a taboo subject, and that there a lot of misunderstood points and lots of discussions regarding it. In any way, I feel I haven't seen an answer that addresses my particular problem. And so here it goes.

I am working on a WPF "TCP logger" application using the MVVM Light Toolkit to "inject" my View-model into the View's DataContext. One of the controls on the View is the "Log" TextBox which is bound, using a Converter, to an ObservableCollection of "LogEntries". This TextBox/ObservableCollection combo might get filled with thousands of items, because my application might be running for days without being closed.

To illustrate what I've explained so far, here's a bit of what we love the most, code:

```
<Window ... DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, 
                                  Path=PortListenerVM}"...>

<TextBox IsReadOnly="True">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{x:Static l:Converters.LogEntryCollectionToTextConverter}">
            <Binding Path="LogEntries" Mode="OneWay"/>
            <Binding Path="UseTimeStamp"/>
            <Binding Path="LogEntries.Count" Mode="OneWay" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

And in the VM:

```
// The MVVM Light Toolkit part
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<PortListenerViewModel>();
    }

    public PortListenerViewModel PortListenerVM
    {
        get
        {
            PortListenerViewModel portListenerVM = 
                ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<PortListenerViewModel>();
            return portListenerVM;
        }
    }
}    

// The damned collection which hogs memory
public ObservableCollection<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }

// The command which should work wonders by releasing memory
public void ClearLog()
{
    this.SelectedListenerFromObject.LogEntries.Clear();
    this.SelectedListenerFromObject.HasTooManyLogEntries = false;
}
```

And so, like any optimistic person, I had expected the Clear method to release the needed memory as soon as the Garbage Collector had done its job. Nope. And "nulling" the Collection and forcing a GC.Collect also did nothing. I've found out afterwards that that brings nothing if something else has still a reference to the Collection.

I'm now coming to the gist of my question. Firstly, how can I find out who's keeping a reference to the LogEntries Collection? Secondly, could the View's DataContext be the culprit, and if so, how would I come about to release the references it has to the Collection (keeping in mind I'm using the Toolkit's ViewModelLocator)?

Second part to my question would be, since the Task Manager apparently doesn't report accurate memory usage, what would be the best way to evaluate how much memory my application is eating? I've been using [System Explorer](http://systemexplorer.net/), which shows different numbers as Task Manager, but are those to be trusted too?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there isn't a problem. The GC is very lazy and task manager shows the memory allocated which is different to what the GC is actually using. The GC may have the objects in a disposable list but just sees no point to it just yet.

Write yourself a test of loading 100,000 items and then clearing the collection. Leave that running overnight.

Comment: 18 hours after loading and clearing 100'000 items, the Mem Usage in System Explorer shows 128'980 K, down from 156'520 K before clearing. The starting memory usage is around 58'000 K. It seems waiting isn't really the solution.